# One of two field is required in drupal 7 view?

Tags: views, entities

I have one view in which i want to upload picture(image) or embed video(text). I want to add condition either picture or video field required. and also user can not fill both value user can fill only one value.

I also tried to use https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields but it can not work for me.

I reffered https://drupal.org/node/355264 . I hope this will help me but I am new in Drupal so how can I used this.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be adding a previous radio button field where the user must select which field is going to fill, and the show this field with conditional field. (Both fields should be required)

Comment: On base this radio button how can i show/hide image or video in form.